# st_intersects Vs st_overlaps

Tags: sql, postgis, spatial, overlap

What is the difference between these two queries :

```
select a.gid, sum(length(b.the_geom)) 
  from polygons as a 
     , roads as b 
 where st_intersects(a.the_geom,b.the_geom) 
 group by a.gid ;

select a.gid, sum(length(b.the_geom)) 
  from polygons as a 
     , roads as b 
 where st_overlaps(a.the_geom,b.the_geom) 
 group by a.gid ;
```

Where the first query is giving the correct output whereas the second query retrieves no rows at all. The road that intersects the polygons also overlaps it, right?

Comment: I suppose you are talking about PostGIS, because st_overlaps and st_intersects exists in PostGIS in exactly that writing. So I add the tag "postgis"... hope thats ok

Comment: @alfonx Considering that the accepted answer is for SQL Server, I don't think [tag:postgis] is an appropriate tag.

Comment: yes, this is postGIS related Query only.

Comment: @Abhishek Sagar please reconsider marking the correct answer. I added one for PostGIS. thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the documentation of PostGIS

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html

> If a geometry or geography shares any portion of space then they intersect. Overlaps, Touches, Within all imply spatial intersection. If any of
>   the aforementioned returns true, then the geometries also spatially
>   intersect.

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Overlaps.html

> Returns TRUE if the Geometries "spatially overlap". By that we mean
>   they intersect, but one does not completely contain another.

The difference is: If two geometries overlap 100%, they do not overlap any more.

Here is a POSTGIS example:

```
SELECT ST_Overlaps(a,b) As a_overlap_b, ST_Intersects(a, b) As a_intersects_b, ST_Contains(b, a) As b_contains_a
FROM (SELECT 
    ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1,3 1,3 3,1 1)'), 4326)  As a,
    ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1,3 1,3 3,1 1)'), 4326)  As b)
    As foo;
    -- INTERSECT is TRUE, OVERLAP is FALSE because B equals A

    SELECT ST_Overlaps(a,b) As a_overlap_b, ST_Intersects(a, b) As a_intersects_b, ST_Contains(b, a) As b_contains_a
FROM (SELECT 
    ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1,3 1,3 3,1 1)'), 4326)  As a,
    ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1,4 1,4 4,1 1)'), 4326)  As b)
    As foo;
    -- INTERSECT is TRUE, OVERLAP is FALSE because B contains A

    SELECT ST_Overlaps(a,b) As a_overlap_b, ST_Intersects(a, b) As a_intersects_b, ST_Contains(b, a) As b_contains_a
FROM (SELECT 
    ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0,2 0,2 2,0 0)'), 4326)  As a,
    ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1,3 1,3 3,1 1)'), 4326)  As b)
    As foo;
    -- INTERSECT is TRUE, OVERLAP is TRUE because not all of A intersects B and not all of B intersects A
```

Comment: now, how do those differ from crosses and the example will be complete

Comment: I know this question is a fossil in internet epochs, but it's also worth noting that `ST_Intersects(a,b)` is T for geometries a,b that **touch** (i.e., no point interior to a is interior to b, and vice versa, but they share points on their respective boundaries). My white whale is an undocumented PostGIS function will enable me to stop having to write `where ST_Intersects(a.g1, b.g1) and not ST_Touches(a.g1, b.g1)` (I've got it set as a code snippet, so I only have to write `pg_tni[tab]`... but that's not the point).

Comment: @GT I'm struggling with this currently - adding `and not st_touches(geom, geom)` unfortunately didn't work for me. Query is still returning geoms that share a border instead of overlapping/intersecting. So frustrating