# SQL Server geometry STIntersects Area

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlgeometry

I have some shapes in my db stored as geometry polygon and I want to check:

1- They don't overlap eachother.

2- No problem if having a shared edge or corner.

I tried STIntersects and it works fine for rule 1 but it returns true for neighbor shapes which shared a corner or edge.

What should I do to achieve my exact result?

Comment: Have you checked STOverlaps? I'm not exactly sure if this does what you want, but you might want to check it out. Or maybe a combination of the two. Also, you might want to check out this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480320/st-intersects-vs-st-overlaps .

Comment: @martennis  Yes. That's It. Thanks.